# Replacing WinInet with WinHttp

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl, wininet, winhttp

I have an old C++Builder project that uses `WinInet.lib` functions to create FTP connections. I want to replace this with WinHttp now, since WinInet is not supported on Windows Server 2019.

To replace WinInet, I commented out `#pragma link "WININET.LIB"` in my main cpp file. Then, in the file where I used these functions, I added the header files I need:

```cpp
#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

// Testing 2021-6-14
#include <windows.h>
#include <winhttp.h>
// Testing 2021-6-14

/* Followed by some more #include */
```

After compiling, I am getting E2238/E2344 errors ("Multiple declaration for.../Earlier declaration of...") - I even tried commenting out the old WinInet functions in this file. Somehow, my project is still being linked to `WinInet.lib`, what is the easiest way to "unlink" it?

Edit 1: Error messages after build

```
[bcc32 Error] winhttp.h(115): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'HTTP_VERSION_INFO'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] wininet.h(486): E2344 Earlier declaration of 'HTTP_VERSION_INFO'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] winhttp.h(115): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'LPHTTP_VERSION_INFO'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] wininet.h(486): E2344 Earlier declaration of 'LPHTTP_VERSION_INFO'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] winhttp.h(122): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'INTERNET_SCHEME'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] wininet.h(305): E2344 Earlier declaration of 'INTERNET_SCHEME'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] winhttp.h(122): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'LPINTERNET_SCHEME'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] wininet.h(305): E2344 Earlier declaration of 'LPINTERNET_SCHEME'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] winhttp.h(167): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'URL_COMPONENTS'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] wininet.h(582): E2344 Earlier declaration of 'URL_COMPONENTS'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] winhttp.h(167): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'LPURL_COMPONENTS'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] wininet.h(583): E2344 Earlier declaration of 'LPURL_COMPONENTS'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] winhttp.h(169): E2015 Ambiguity between 'URL_COMPONENTS' and 'Winapi::Wininet::URL_COMPONENTS'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] winhttp.h(169): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'URL_COMPONENTSW'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] wininet.h(577): E2344 Earlier declaration of 'URL_COMPONENTSW'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] winhttp.h(170): E2238 Multiple declaration for 'LPURL_COMPONENTSW'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
  [bcc32 Error] wininet.h(577): E2344 Earlier declaration of 'LPURL_COMPONENTSW'
    Full parser context
      Export.cpp(32): #include c:\program files (x86)\embarcadero\studio\21.0\include\windows\sdk\winhttp.h
```

Comment: "*WinInet is not supported on Windows Server 2019*" - why do you think that? WinInet predates WS2019, and Microsoft is not in the habit of removing old APIs. In any case, double-check your project settings for `.lib` references that need to be removed. But the errors you are seeing are **compiler** errors, not **linker** errors, so you have a conflict between header files. Also note that `Vcl.h` already includes `windows.h` for you, so you can remove that. As for the errors themselves, which symbols *exactly* are being complained about? Please provide the error messages verbatim.

Comment: According to [this page from the official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/wininet/wininet-vs-winhttp), you should generally choose WinINet over WinHTTP. Therefore, I severely doubt that your argument for choosing WinHTTP is valid.

Comment: Also, WinHTTP is just HTTP only, it doesn't support FTP, like WinInet does.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Please see my edit for the error messages. It is just like you said, there are conflicts between `winhttp.h` and `wininet.h`

Comment: The error messages you quote do not imply that `wininet.h` is even involved.  But even if it is, just take it out of your code.  Don't include both `wininet.h` and `winhttp.h` in the same translation unit. It would be more helpful if you provided a [mcve] that demonstrates the errors in action.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau "WinInet is not supported on Windows Server 2019" - I actually opened up a case with Embarcadero and I was told that WinInet is not supported. This lines up with another project I was testing. This other project consisted of many tasks, one used WinInet functions but the .exe could not start because of 0xC0000142 error. After splitting up the tasks into separate .exe files and removing the use of WinInet allowed these programs to run on Windows Server 2019. Now I'm trying to do the same for this project, but I still need some functionality like WinInet

Comment: There are many 3rd party libraries for C++ that provide FTP/HTTP functionality without relying on WinInet/WinHTTP. Since you are using C++Builder, it comes with Indy pre-installed, which has `TIdFTP` and `TIdHTTP` components, for instance. Or, you could simply use WinSock directly to implement those protocols yourself in your own code.